# What is a good online computer keyboard piano source that includes the cello sound as well?

Tags: keyboard, digital-piano

I have been using two simple free online computer keyboard pianos http://virtualpiano.net/ and https://www.onlinepianist.com/virtual-piano but they are getting really boring to me (I used to play on a real keyboard with many instrument options). What is a good online source for one that also includes other instrument sounds, but specifically the **cello** and preferably other string instruments as well? It's ok if it's not free, I would just prefer it to be new user friendly. Whenever I look for downloads, from app stores, they seem either overly complicated(i.e. difficult to just dive in and play freely) or too basic with only a few keys. An ability for it to record and add layers would be really cool too, but I have yet to find one.

Comment: If you want anything that really deserves to be called “cello sound” you'll have to live with a somewhat more complicated interface than for piano etc.. There's no way to approximate the expressive range of string instruments by simply pressing down keys on an ordinary keyboard.

Comment: ...anyway I find that even high-end plugins such as Blakus Cello, despite having a pretty stunning amount of expressive possibilities, are ultimately unsatisfying. If what you want is a cello sound then what you need is a cellist! If you have good musical ideas then _write them out_ – you don't need any string instruments to do that – and consult with a cellist for how it'll really sound.

Comment: And as for recording and layering... that's something you should do with a generic [DAW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_workstation), independent of what sounds you actually use. I recommend [Reaper](http://reaper.fm/).

Comment: MIDI sampler?  Mellotron? :-) .  Depends on the quality you want.  Most folks think the intro song for Game of Thrones comes from real cellos, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was wondering the same thing but unfortunately i couldnt find any really simple websites like the ones you linked. i think you might be better off using a real electronic piano keyboard but maybe a small one that you can just connect to your pc/computer and atleast that way youll have the normal piano keys to press and not the computer keyboard.

Comment: @ErikaRizk I had this same dilemma after I had to move, which meant leaving my actual piano behind. I have a few friends who use these very small electric keyboards, that are almost the size of a computer keyboard that they just hook up to their computer. Its pretty simple/useful as long as you make sure it'll work with your type of computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try Soundation.
The cello is decent as online keyboard goes.
You can also record multi tracks.
https://soundation.com/studio